# Apache authentication with LDAP using a FORM

Tags: ldap

I have authenticated my web site with Ldap server.  Authentication is working fine.
Every time i visit the web site, it pop-up's dailog box for user name and password.

Now, I want to authenticate using a FORM instead of dailog box.  I want to use AuthType Form option in Apache.

Please do the needful

Thanks
shankar Jadapa

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `AuthType Form`. It's either `Basic` or `Digest`. See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#authtype) for more details.

You would normally implement form based authentication in your application, with three parts:

1. A login form for the user to fill out with their username and password.
2. A page that the form is submitted to that returns a cookie to the browser
3. A check at the top of every request that checked for that cookie and redirect to the login page if it isn't there.

There is nothing in a standard Apache distribution to do this for you.

**Edit**: Seems there is a [`mod_auth_form`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_auth_form.html) in Apache 2.3, which isn't released yet.